# In Flutter, how do I check if an email address entered in TextField exists in Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In Flutter, how do I check if an email address entered in TextField exists in Firebase
I tried this but I couldn't get the result. What should be done to solve this?

```
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
 
            TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-posta'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                style: context.general.textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                  color: ColorConstants.colorsWhite,
                )),
            CustomButton(
              description: 'Send Code',
              backgroundColor: ColorConstants.colorBlue,
              onPressed: () {
                String email = emailController.text;

                passwordReset(email);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
  
 Future<void> passwordReset(
      String email,
    ) async {
      try {
        
        var methods =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);

        if (methods.isNotEmpty) {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
          
        } else {
          print('email not found');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('error: $e');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On projects that were created on September 15 or later, Firebase's [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is enabled by default. This secures your users against email enumeration attacks, but unfortunately means that `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` will no longer return any results (as that is precisely what allows an email enumeration attack).

You'll either have to [disable the email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable) (which can also be done from [this page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) in the Firebase console), or stop relying on the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` API.