# Why is my Firebase Authentication Error code "invalid-authentication" instead of "user-not-found"?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When I am trying to enter the credentials which are not registered it  returns "invalid-credentials" error instead of "user-not found" .

```
try {
    final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    print(userCredential);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print("FirebaseAuthException: $e");
    print("Complete exception details: ${e.toString()}");

    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      print('User not found');
    } else {
      // Handle other specific error cases if needed
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's.your question? why is it returning a different error then you thought? or how to _handle_ the different errror?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I got the solution. there is a security setting on firebase which was by default active that's why I was getting different error (i suspected it because i saw the documentation of firebase)

Answer (score 2):

Firebase optionally provides [protection against email enumeration attachs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) and it seems like that is enabled on your project. With that protection enabled (which it is by default on projects created since September 15), the API returns different responses in order to not leak user information.

You can either [disable the protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable), or modify your app to no longer depends on the flows that were modified.

Also see:

- [I Don't get Error codes of Firebase Auth in my Flutter App (I ONLY get INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l/77250121#77250121)
- [In Flutter, how do I check if an email address entered in TextField exists in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540003/in-flutter-how-do-i-check-if-an-email-address-entered-in-textfield-exists-in-fi/77540033#77540033)
- [Flutter/Firebase Authentication with Email & Password not functioning as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77312410/flutter-firebase-authentication-with-email-password-not-functioning-as-intende/77312743#77312743)